# Bures distance - behaviour with tensor product

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

In several sources (e.g. [this, chapter 4](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.03449.pdf)) I have read the following facts about Bures distance $B(\rho,\tau)$:

1. It has the maximal value (which is independent of the dimension of the Hilbert space) if and only if $\rho$ and $\tau$ have orthogonal support
2. $B(\rho\otimes \rho_1,\tau\otimes \tau_1)\geq B(\rho,\tau)$ with the equality if and only if $ \rho_1=\tau_1$.

But:

Assume, that $\rho$ and $\tau$ have orthogonal support, then 2) cannot be true, as I can choose  $ \rho_1\neq\tau_1$, but $B(\rho\otimes \rho_1,\tau\otimes \tau_1)$ cannot be larger that $B(\rho,\tau)$, as $B(\rho,\tau)$ is already maximal... Isn't this a contradiction?

?!

How one can explain this?

Comment: If $\rho$ and $\tau$ have orthogonal support, then what can you say about the supports of $\rho \otimes \rho_1$ and $\tau \otimes \tau_1$?

Comment: Its support is also orthogonal, but then $B(\rho\otimes \rho_1,\tau\otimes \tau_1) =B(\rho,\tau) $ so if and only if statement in 2. is false

Comment: That's right, statement 2 is not correct in general (it holds only when $\rho$ and $\tau$ have overlapping support).

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirmation!